# Query performance hampered by seemingly light join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I am really perplexed  by the behaviour of this query (changed it to actual query):

```
   select * from fs_export_stage_data_customer m
    cross apply (select count(*) from fs_export_stage_data_customer m2 where m2.inscode=m.inscode) sq1(cnt)
    inner join fs_export_stage_session se on m.session=se.id 
    where cnt>1
    order by m.inscode,m.comb_dbupddate
```

As is, it runs in <1 second. If I uncomment the inner join, it takes more than a minute (don't know exactly how much, didn't have the patience). This is very strange to me, as the session table has only 50 rows (and less than 20 cols), and both session and data_customer have a clustered index on the fields you see in the join condition ALONE. Any ideas?
As requested, I am including the execution plans.

Execution plan with join:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hk1cU3KRb

Comment: Did you use query analyzer or look at the execution plan yet to determine where it might cause so many computations that it slows down by such a large factor?

Comment: I did not. I have seen many question-answers to know that that's what I should have done, but I still am not able to decode its meaning, as I don't know the algorithms very well. Still, give me some time to do this and post the results.

Comment: Paste here your actual execution plan for the query with inner join

Comment: However: if it takes "forever", would the estimated one help?

Comment: You can put here estimated plan, but are you able to answer how many se.id correspond to one m.session? and how many rows really have cnt>1? I expect your estimated plan "thinks" there is a small number of rows and uses Nested Loops, but there are too many rows so it should use Hash join...

Comment: You can try to rewrite your query using inner HASH join session se on m.session=se.id, or using inner MERGE join, if it finishes soon you can get it's actual èplan and put it here along with estimated plan for your query without any hint

Comment: added actual execution plans both with and without the join line

Comment: NOoooo, not as a picture, paste it as xml here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and then update your question with the link to pasted plan

Comment: Have you tried adding an index on `inscode` (as the query plan suggested)? Looks like the DBMS sequentially scans through the entire `data_customer` table for each row (i.e. doing O(N^2) work).

Comment: please paste them as xml and not images.. you can also paste here and share the link..https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: Add the `inner join` back and comment out the `order by` and check again?

Comment: Your query has underestimation, it should not use Nested Loops at least now with the actual indexes. Hash join can help you, but we still expect your actual plan in xml format

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis The query references different tables to the ones shown in the execution plan screenshots?

Also, include `SET STATISTICS IO ON` output in the question for both queries

Comment: added actual execution plan in xml as described...I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said previously, your query has underestimation.
That can be corrected this way:

```
if object_id('tempdb.. #cnt') is not null drop table #cnt;

select inscode, count(*) as cnt
into #cnt
from fs_export_stage_data_customer
group by inscode
having count(*) > 1;


select * 
from fs_export_stage_data_customer m join #cnt c
        on m.inscode=c.inscode
    inner join fs_export_stage_session se 
        on m.session=se.id 
order by m.inscode,m.comb_dbupddate;
```

`#cnt` cardinality will be known and final result cardinality estimation will be correct.

**Explanation**

Here is your execution plan where you can see that your

```
(select count(*) from fs_export_stage_data_customer m2 where m2.inscode=m.inscode) sq1(cnt)
```

is estimated as 1 row, but there are 33.092 rows with count(*) > 1:

[image]

So your join `fs_export_stage_data_customer m inner join fs_export_stage_session se on m.session=se.id` will have 33092 rows, but instead server thinks it will produce only 1 row.

It then executes `Nested Loops` join because of this underestimation (NL performs good for small number of rows), but what we did: we materialized the result of counting filtered by `count(*) > 1`, so server knows that it's going to join 2 tables where one of them does not have 1 row but 33.092, so it could change join type or at least not to put `fs_export_stage_session` as the upper table in `NL` (upper table is supposed to have more rows than lower).

Links for further reading: [Nested Loops Join by Craig Freedman](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/26/nested-loops-join/).

You can find descriprion of other join types in the same blog.

Reguarding NL (from the blog cited above):

> Because the complexity of a nested loops join is proportional to the
>   **size of the outer input multiplied by the size of the inner input**, a
>   nested loops join generally **performs best for relatively small input
>   sets**.  The inner input need not be small, but, if it is large, it
>   helps to include an index on a highly selective join key.

Comment: 6 seconds, not bad! You've missed the group by inscode btw. But, can you please either explain, or provide links for further information, about underestimation and cardinality?

Comment: I updated my answer adding group by, explanation and further reading link

Comment: Thank you very much for this rich answer!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this. First get the result and then do the join.

```
WITH Cte
     AS (
     SELECT M.Session
     FROM Data_Customer AS M
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Data_Customer
           WHERE Inscode = M.Inscode
                                    ) AS Sq1(Cnt)
     WHERE Cnt > 1
     ORDER BY M.Inscode,
          M.Comb_Dbupddate)
     SELECT *
     FROM Cte AS C
       INNER JOIN Session AS Se ON C.Session = Se.Id;
```

Comment: After removing the order within the cte, I gotta say it runs as slowly as my version.

Comment: This is because any CTE is expanded prior to be executed, to I bet the execution plan for original query and this one with CTE IS THE SAME

Answer (score 0):

Variants:

Add nonclustered index on inscode

Add OPTION(FORCE ORDER) this may by return HASH PLAN

You have a huge difference between estimate and actual: no have statistic/index

```
SELECT  
    m.session 
FROM data_customer m
INNER JOIN -- if no index on inscode may by try INNER HASH JOIN or create index
(
    SELECT inscode
    FROM data_customer 
    GROUP BY inscode
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) as b
ON
    b.inscode = m.inscode
INNER JOIN 
    session se 
ON 
    m.session = se.id 
ORDER BY 
    m.inscode,
    m.comb_dbupddate
```

Comment: I tried this already. Still slow. Don't mistrust our dear cross apply ;)

Comment: Do you fundamentally ignore the recommendations of the db engine?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Green text on your screen :) CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ... inscode

Comment: Please note that the nonexistence of an index on inscode is present in both my queries, and the first query runs in milliseconds. Isn't it safe to say, then, that this is not the problem?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis They are not same queries, therefore DBMS chooses a different plan. In this case, it seems it's not smart enough to choose a HASH JOIN for the second as well (probably due underestimating number of rows), but why not help it by index even if the plan is "wrong"? Otherwise, you may try table hints, or updating statistics (which may be the actual root cause of the "wrong" plan)...

Comment: NL + scan vs HASH + scan ... continue not to see the difference

Comment: @TapakahUa HASH MATCH scans once, NESTED LOOPS scans for each row. Its an O(N) vs. O(N^2) difference.

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic Do not explain the difference to me